# Should I keep in contact with a recruiter?

Tags: communication, recruitment

I've recently gotten a job with what I think is a good recruiter. The recruiter works with an independent company than my employer, but she was nice, knew my needs, and knew what kind of position would fit me.

I have a friend who keeps in regular contact with his recruiter, but from the recruiter questions I've seen on this site, there seems to be some things I would need to watch out such as the recruiter keeping my resume information.

My question is, are there any danger or negatives in keeping contact with a recruiter? Are there any pitfalls I should worry about?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Short answer:** If you find a good recruiter, hold on to them!

I have had a couple of recruiters over the years who I found went the extra mile for me, so the next time I looked for a new role, I immediately contacted them first.  Because of our successful previous interaction, they could speak with confidence to a potential employer about my capability.  From my part, I knew that they could close a contract, which improved my confidence in them.

Of course, they may not have anything, but I always find it valuable to keep every possible avenue and ally available if I go job hunting.

Comment: And a good recruiter knows your current situation.  I do lunch or coffee with mine every 3 months or so.  It can be a rather innocuous conversation that could lead to a great opportunity later.

Answer (score 4):

As Jane points out in her answer, it's a great idea to keep in touch with a good recruiter.

However, tying yourself down to the one recruiter might not be a good thing as you'll obviously miss out on other opportunities.  You also don't know whether "your" recruiter is as effective as negotiating rates/position as any other recruiter.

So, I'd keep in touch with this recruiter, but also keep my options open with others should I feel I needed an extra edge.

Answer (score 2):

Something to keep in mind is recruiters make their money by putting people in new jobs.  If you enjoy socializing with them, by all means, have a good time, but keep in mind they are keeping the relationship going because they want to place you again.

If you are happy in your current job and expect to be there for an indefinite period, I would suggest that you keep your relationship with your recruiter quiet.  If it gets around you are talking to a recruiter it may be perceived that you are not satisfied and are looking for another job which will mean you will be passed over for things in favor of people who management expects to be around for a while.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain a relationship because you like them as a person, all the power to you.

From a professional standpoint, the recruiter is not "useful" to you outside of when you are considering new employment. When you are in this position, recruiters are *very* happy to rekindle any relationship you previously had, as their livelihood is based on matching employees with employers.

I wouldn't feel at risk of "losing" a recruiter you like due to not maintaining the relationship.

Answer (score -1):

One of the downsides I would say is they could use you as potential candidate source. I've had one that tried to keep contact. All very polite but conversations always drifted quickly to do I know anyone else looking to leave my previous employer.

Comment: Because they aren't helping you, they are just using you to find them more talent for virtually no effort on their part. I call that doing their job for them.